# Authorize user by retrieving credentials from LDAP and passing into OAuth 1.0a using Atlassian Stash REST API

Tags: rest, oauth, ldap, authorization, bitbucket-server

I have found some projects, but I am really unsure if they are what I want.

Maybe you could give some tutorials or examples, how and where in Stash I can pass ldap credetials? Docs explains only GUI way to do that....

Thank you very, very much.

UPDATE: Question made in Atlassians "Ask" : https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17893290/how-to-integrate-ldap-when-installing-in-puppet#

Comment: Why are you looking to pass credentials to OAUTH? A big advantage of OAUTH is that the service provider (your app) can be separate from the identity provider (Atlassian's OAUTH server) and that a user doesn't need to tell the service provider their credentials.

Comment: OK, then what would be could correct way? In the end what I need is to be set config that would enable user to log in in Stash using LDAP from CLI (REST API), not GUI...